# Android Stripe payment sheet callback not called

Tags: android, stripe-payments

I followed [these](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=android) instructions in 2 projects. Exact same code in both. In one project, everything works, the payment, the webhook call on the back-end, the callback in the `new PaymentSheet(this, new PaymentSheetResultCallback() {...}`. On the other project, on the other hand, everything works, EXCEPT the callback of the native code, the `PaymentSheetResultCallback()`.

I tried using the same `ephemeralKey` and `publishableKey`, etc from the project that doesn't work in the one that does work, and the callback is indeed called.

I have absolutely no idea what the difference is. No clue where to start looking to be frank.

I tried moving the logic in another Activity, as I thought that activity is a "strange" one for some reason ... didn't work. My single guess is for some reason the SDKs callback when it comes back from their Sheet view, is not triggered and it doesn't pass the data to the callback. But I have no idea how to check and fix that. Any other ideas ?!

Here's my implementation for clarity:

```
    mPaymentSheet = new PaymentSheet(this, new PaymentSheetResultCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onPaymentSheetResult(@NonNull PaymentSheetResult paymentSheetResult) {

            /**  THIS IS NEVER CALLED !   */

            System.out.println("BUBU :: STRIPE :: huh?! :: " + paymentSheetResult);
            if (paymentSheetResult instanceof PaymentSheetResult.Canceled) {
                System.out.println("BUBU :: STRIPE :: canceled");
            } else if (paymentSheetResult instanceof PaymentSheetResult.Failed) {
                System.out.println("BUBU :: STRIPE :: error " + ((PaymentSheetResult.Failed) paymentSheetResult).getError().getMessage());
            } else if (paymentSheetResult instanceof PaymentSheetResult.Completed) {
                System.out.println("BUBU :: STRIPE :: WOOOOT !!!!");
            }
        }
    });
```

And

```
                    PaymentConfiguration.init(APaymentSummary.this,
                                resp.getPublishableKey()
                        );

                    PaymentSheet.Address address = new PaymentSheet.Address(
                            null,
                            HUser.instance().getUserCountry(),
                            null, null, null, null
                    );
                    PaymentSheet.BillingDetails.Builder billingDetails =
                            new PaymentSheet.BillingDetails.Builder().address(address);

                    PaymentSheet.CustomerConfiguration customerConfiguration = new PaymentSheet.CustomerConfiguration(
                            resp.getCustomer(),
                            resp.getEphemeralKey()
                    );

                    PaymentSheet.GooglePayConfiguration googlePayConfiguration = new PaymentSheet.GooglePayConfiguration(
                            PaymentSheet.GooglePayConfiguration.Environment.Test,
                            HUser.instance().getUserCountry(),
                            getTopupHolder().getSelectedTopup().getTotalValueCurrencyCode()
                    );

                    mPaymentSheet.presentWithPaymentIntent(
                            resp.getPaymentIntent(),
                            new PaymentSheet.Configuration(
                                    "Sift",
                                    customerConfiguration,
                                    googlePayConfiguration,
                                    null,
                                    billingDetails.build()
                            )
                    );
```

Payment goes through ok in the back-end webhook, but nothing is triggered on my end.

Help ?!

**EDIT**
There aren't ANY logs from the Stripe SDK either ...

Answer (score 1):

Such a simple fix ....

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data); <--- I was never calling this ! So it was never reaching the SDK to let it handle the Intent data coming from their Sheet Activity
    /*...*/
}
```